Trigger file download after fetching the data in an efficient way
Is there any other cross-browser way to trigger a file download after fetching the data using fetch? For now I'm using
const response = await fetch(url);
const blob = await response.blob();
const a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
a.download = 'file';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
a.remove();

But it first fetches whole file into memory. Is there any way to do it without putting it all into memory first?

Don't use fetch() in the first place. Set the href of the anchor to the URL.

Btw you forgot to revokeObjectURL() afterwards…

@Barmar won't work with cross-origin resources though, even the ones that do allow cross-origin fetches. To OP, do you manage the server where the resource is coming from? Is it same-origin with your page? If not, can you change the headers it's served with? In that case just make it return a Content-Disposition: attachment header. Otherwise if you're targeting Chromium browsers only, then it's doable. Otherwise it's still doable but more convoluted.
